# JavaDB: get ordered records in the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, subquery, offset, javadb

I have the following "COMPANIES_BY_NEWS_REPUTATION" in my JavaDB database (this is some random data just to represent the structure)

```
      COMPANY         |  NEWS_HASH       | REPUTATION     | DATE
-------------------------------------------------------------------
      Company A       |   14676757       | 0.12345        | 2011-05-19 15:43:28.0                         
      Company B       |   454564556      | 0.78956        | 2011-05-24 18:44:28.0
      Company C       |   454564556      | 0.78956        | 2011-05-24 18:44:28.0
      Company A       |   -7874564       | 0.12345        | 2011-05-19 15:43:28.0
```

One news_hash may relate to several companies while a company can relate to several news_hashes as well. Reputation and date are bound to the news_hash.

What I need to do is calculate the average reputation of last 5 news for every company. In order to do that I somehow feel that I need to user 'order by' and 'offset' in a subquery as shown in the code below.

```
select COMPANY, avg(REPUTATION) from 
   (select * from COMPANY_BY_NEWS_REPUTATION order by "DATE" desc
   offset 0 rows fetch next 5 row only) as TR group by COMPANY;
```

However, JavaDB allows neither ORDER BY, nor OFFSET in a subquery. Could anyone suggest a working solution for my problem please?

Comment: How do you calculate average reputation? Is it average across all tuples or just the last 5 values

Comment: Let's assume the subquery is acceptable, means you are only getting the last 5 rows in that reputation table, that could mean say 4 data points for company A, 1 data point for B and none for C (assuming that's the last 5) - then your avg(Reputation) for A is out of 4 data points, for B is out of 1, and for C there would be none?

Comment: Yes, you are right, even if the query was accepted, it would not return what I need...

Answer (score 1):

Which version of JavaDB are you using? According to the chapter [TableSubquery](http://download.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rreftablesubquery.html) in the JavaDB documentation, table subqueries do support `order by` and `fetch next`, at least in version 10.6.2.1.

Given that subqueries can be ordered and the size of the result set can be limited, the following (untested) query might do what you want:

```
select COMPANY, (select avg(REPUTATION) 
                 from (select REPUTATION 
                       from COMPANY_BY_NEWS_REPUTATION
                       where COMPANY = TR.COMPANY
                       order by DATE desc
                       fetch first 5 rows only))
from (select distinct COMPANY 
      from COMPANY_BY_NEWS_REPUTATION) as TR
```

This query retrieves all distinct company names from `COMPANY_BY_NEWS_REPUTATION`, then retrieves the average of the last five reputation rows for each company. I have no idea whether it will perform sufficiently, that will likely depend on the size of your data set and what indexes you have in place.

If you have a list of unique company names in another table, you can use that instead of the `select distinct ...` subquery to retrieve the companies for which to calculate averages.